# use length function in substring in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, substring, string-length

I am trying to use the length function inside a substring function in a `DataFrame`
but it gives error

```
val substrDF = testDF.withColumn("newcol", substring($"col", 1, length($"col")-1))
```

below is the error

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Int
```

I am using 2.1.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Function "expr" can be used:

```
val data = List("first", "second", "third")
val df = sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("value")
val result = df.withColumn("cutted", expr("substring(value, 1, length(value)-1)"))
result.show(false)
```

output:

```
+------+------+
|value |cutted|
+------+------+
|first |firs  |
|second|secon |
|third |thir  |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Why use length at all here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69863053/11221104

Answer (score 18):

You could also use $"COLUMN".[substr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@substr(startPos:Int,len:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```
val substrDF = testDF.withColumn("newcol", $"col".substr(lit(1), length($"col")-1))
```

Output:

```
val testDF = sc.parallelize(List("first", "second", "third")).toDF("col")
val result = testDF.withColumn("newcol", $"col".substr(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(1), length($"col")-1))
result.show(false)
+------+------+
|col   |newcol|
+------+------+
|first |firs  |
|second|secon |
|third |thir  |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Imho this is a much better solution as it allows you to build custom functions taking a column and returning a column. E.g. in pyspark `def foo(in:Column)->Column: return in.substr(2, length(in))` Without relying on aliases of the column (which you would have to with the `expr` as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because you the signature of `substring` is

```
def substring(str: Column, pos: Int, len: Int): Column
```

The `len` argument that you are passing is a `Column`, and should be an `Int`.

You may probably want to implement a simple UDF to solve that problem.

```
val strTail = udf((str: String) => str.substring(1))
testDF.withColumn("newCol", strTail($"col"))
```

Comment: Only implement customs udfs if it is really necessary as they are slower that built in functions. For this case this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to remove the last character of the string, you can do that without UDF as well. By using `regexp_replace` :

```
testDF.show
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|abcd|
|  2|qazx|
+---+----+

testDF.withColumn("newcol", regexp_replace($"name", ".$" , "") ).show
+---+----+------+
| id|name|newcol|
+---+----+------+
|  1|abcd|   abc|
|  2|qazx|   qaz|
+---+----+------+
```

Comment: I think a regex is an overkill for this.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the SUBSTR function to achieve this.

```
val substrDF = testDF.withColumn("newcol", 'col.substr(lit(1), length('col)-1))
```

The first parameter is the position from which you want the data to be trimmed, the second parameter is the length of the trimmed field.
(startPos: Int,len: Int)